# Angular 6: no singleton for service and pass info to configuration a module

Tags: angular, typescript, singleton

My app has this structure:

```
src
 |-- modules
 |  |-- app2-module
 |  
 |-- shared-common
 |  |-- services
 |      |-- rest.services.ts
 |
 |-- app.module.ts
```

The rest.services has to be configurable.

If it called in app2 (`app2-module`) the get methods use, for example, 
`rest/app2-api/getCompanyList`; if it called in app1 (`app.module.ts`) the get methods use, for example, `rest/app1-api/getCompanyList`.

So I create a configurable shared module in this way

```
export default interface SharedCommonConfig {
    createApiUrl(api: string): string;
}

export const SharedCommonConfigService): = new InjectionToken<SharedCommonConfig>('SharedCommonConfig');

export class SharedCommonModule {
    static forRoot(config: SharedCommonConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedCommonModule 
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: SharedCommonConfigService): Service,
                    useValue: config
                },
                RestService
            ],
        };
    }
}
```

and I pass the configuration in `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({

    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        App2Module,
        SharedCommonModule .forRoot({
            createApiUrl: (api: string) => {    
                return `/rest/app1-app/${api}`;
            }
        })
    ],

})

export class AppModule implements OnInit {}
```

and in App2Module

```
@NgModule({

    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
         SharedCommonModule .forRoot({
            createApiUrl: (api: string) => {    
                return `/rest/app2-app/${api}`;
            }
        })
    ],

})

export class App2Module implements OnInit {}
```

App2Module is showed on screen when the user navigate to url http://example.com/#/app2/ and in this case the rest service has to call the api with `/rest/app2-app` as a prefix; but it's not work because read only the configuration in app.module.ts.

Is it possibile don't use the rest.service as singleton?

Answer (score 0):

The action of importing the shared service in the root app.module in this way will make it a singleton.

To avoid this, you would need to separate app1.module and app2.module and then register the service in both of those and *not* register it in the main app.module.

Therefore, you would need:

```
@NgModule({

    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        App1Module,
        App2Module
    ],

})
export class AppModule implements OnInit {}
```

... and then separate App1Module and App2Module both registering the shared module as you have done for App2Module:

App 1:

```
@NgModule({

    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        SharedCommonModule .forRoot({
            createApiUrl: (api: string) => {    
                return `/rest/app1-app/${api}`;
            }
        })
    ],

})
export class App1Module implements OnInit {}
```

App 2:

```
@NgModule({

    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        SharedCommonModule .forRoot({
            createApiUrl: (api: string) => {    
                return `/rest/app2-app/${api}`;
            }
        })
    ],

})
export class App2Module implements OnInit {}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example? I started using Angular for a few weeks

Comment: You already have an example in your question - exactly the same as you have done for App2Module. If you register the shared module in your root app.module, it will always have a single instance of this service as you have found, so for this case where you need different instances for different parts of the application, you must not register it in the root app.module. I'll  update my answer to try and show what I mean.

Comment: @Webman I've updated the answer to give a more concrete explanation.

Comment: I didn't have time to try your solution. I will do tomorrow, I think